# "world cup 2011 is done with" or "you are done with 2011 world cup"

Tags: sentence-construction

> So this World Cup is over for you Imran Khan, World Cup 2011 is done with.

Is that sentence correct, or should it be:

> So this world cup is over for you Imran Khan, you are done with 2011 World Cup.

Comment: Others may see things different, but I don't think ***to be done with [something]*** works very well in this exact context. Apart from the fact that it's a distinctly "slangy" usage, I normally understand it as implying *to have had enough [of something], to **no longer wish to engage with** [something]*. It would make more sense to me as *The World Cup is **done with you*** (meaning the competition has no further need for defeated players, not that a player no longer cares about the competition).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  It depends on what exactly is meant by "over for you" / "done with".  2011 was a long time ago, and since I can only assume this is topically related to [recent statements by Imran Khan](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/india-condemns-provocative-statements-against-it-by-imran-khan/articleshow/70893262.cms), I'd like to know how the two are supposed to relate to each other.  It may work, or it may be another idiom is better.

Comment: @Andrew: Agreed. I've no idea *exactly* what the text is supposed to convey - just making the point that to me at least, *X is over for Y* implies Y has lost *something that he wanted* (he regrets losing it), whereas *Y is done with X* implies Y *no longer wants X* (he's glad to see the back of it).

Answer (score 1):

> World Cup 2011 is done with

means that it is entirely finished and over for everyone.

> you are done with **the** 2011 World Cup

means that Imran Khan will have nothing more to do with the 2011 World Cup. The cup may still be continuing.

Note that "the" is necessary to make the sentence correct.